# Python url construction: escape characters other than regular letters

Tags: python, url-rewriting, mediawiki

I am using wikipedia api and using following api request,

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?`action=query&meta=globaluserinfo&guiuser='$cammer'&guiprop=groups|merged|unattached&format=json`
```

but the problem is I am unable to escape Dollar Sign and similar characters like that, I tried the following but it didn't work,

```
    r['guiprop'] = u'groups|merged|unattached'
    r['guiuser'] = u'$cammer'
```

I found it this in w3school but checking this for every single character would a pain full, what would be the best way to escape this in the `strip.http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at using [urlencode](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode).

```
from urllib import urlencode

base_url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?"

arguments = dict(action="query",
                 meta="globaluserinfo",
                 guiuser="$cammer",
                 guiprop="groups|merged|unattached",
                 format="json")
url = base_url + urlencode(arguments)
```

If you don't need to build a complete url you can just use the [quote](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) function for a single string:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.quote("$cammer")
'%24cammer'
```

So you end up with:

```
r['guiprop'] = urllib.quote(u'groups|merged|unattached')
r['guiuser'] = urllib.quote(u'$cammer')
```

Comment: I am using a api called called pywiki bot so I don't really have to construct the url, how can just encode just one string. Thanks, like $cammer for example

Comment: right the problem is i will be sending list of user_names and I want to do something like if a string has such character replace it. Any good way to do this?

Comment: it didn't i tried it like this         user_name = '$cammer'
        r['guiprop'] = u'groups|merged|unattached'
        r['guiuser'] = urllib.quote(user_name) #need to figure how to do the unicode
        data = r.submit()

Comment: It could be that whatever library you are using is also trying to do its own encoding. Is there any way you could find out what the actual final is?

Comment: I am trying to figure how to find the final value. this is the api i am using http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Pywikibot/wikipedia.py